Inclined offer from Amazon without finding a team
I got a verbal inclined offer from Amazon after the loop interview for an SDE II role in the US, but due to VISA issues (H-1B lottery not won), I have started looking for teams in London where I am currently based.
I have had some, what they call informal, Hiring Manager calls, but no success for matching me a team. I have been speaking with a few recruiters now. They all assure me that Amazon would like to work with me based on my interview results, but it seems that even passing the technical interviews and being in the top 2% is not enough to get a job there.
The inclined offer is valid for 6 months, and I am soon at the 3 months mark.
Has anyone been in a similar situation before? What could I do from my end?

You are currently in the UK. I assume there are Amazon locations in the UK with SDE jobs. Can you ask Amazon to see if they can help you finding an SDE job there ? -- Or can you apply for Amazon SDE jobs in the UK directly ?

@Job_September_2020: yes, thanks. I tried applying directly, but no job applications get answers. Yes, both the US recruiter and me are reaching out to UK recruiters. I had 3 Hiring Manager calls with three different teams, but none was successful.

What is an "inclined offer"? It clearly isn't an actual job offer...

@keshlam From a web search, "inclined" seems to be an Amazon-specific term meaning "you did well at interview but we don't actually have a role for you".

Ok, donut just means you haven't actively been declined yet. Don't get hung up on it, continue interviewing everywhere until you get a real offer you like.

...and there I was thinking an "inclined offer" meant you had to have sufficient degrees.

Amazon is FAANG and all... but if you want to work there be careful of what team you join... They had a pretty toxic work culture created by leadership... and I am pretty sure they still do as their leadership that created said culture is still there.

A Reddit post on inclined offers suggests that Amazon actually passed on hiring you. Even if you were offered a job, it most certainly was conditional, on your visa issues.

Looking back at my last post: "donut"? Probably intended to be "then it". Though it sounds like a donut in the sense of zero; all you know is you haven't been actively rejected yet. That and three dollars will get you a cup of Storebought's coffee..

OP, congrats on getting the offer from Amazon! Found myself in a similar situation. Read online that team matching could take several months ~ forever so the offer sizzled off :(. Can you share more details about your journey? What helped you land a job eventually?

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review


They all assure me that Amazon would like to work with me based on my interview results

With all due respect, that's just polite words. They haven't made you a job offer and show no real intention to do so. By all means stay in touch with the recruiters at Amazon, but keep up your job hunt elsewhere.

Thanks, the question was meant to be specifically what could be done at Amazon. I have some offers also from Fintech and elsewhere, but I wanted to work for Amazon. I think I found some helpful answers on the internet what more I could try at Amazon from my side and I also have some ideas in addition. Thanks again.

To put it more straightforwardly: Amazon aren't going to offer you a job. It's time to move on.

Update: got an offer!

As the old saying goes:
"Verbal Contracts are not worth the paper they are printed on"
If you don't have it in writing, you don't have it.

I have got an offer in the end, thanks!
